# Why does this Python generator/coroutine lose a value?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Reading about Python coroutines, I came across this code:

```
def countdown(n):
    print("Start from {}".format(n))
    while n >= 0:
        print("Yielding {}".format(n))
        newv = yield n
        if newv is not None:
            n = newv
        else:
            n -= 1

c = countdown(5)
for n in c:
    print(n)
    if n == 5: c.send(2)
```

which curiously outputs:

```
Start from 5
Yielding 5
5
Yielding 3
Yielding 2
2
Yielding 1
1
Yielding 0
0
```

In particular, it misses printing the `3`. Why?

---

The referenced question does not answer this question because I am not asking what `send` does. It sends values back into the function. What I am asking is why, after I issue `send(3)`, does the next yield, which should yield 3, not cause the for loop to print 3.

Comment: First, it misses 4 as well. Second, what do you think `c.send(3)` does ?

Comment: @alfasin It misses the 4 because of `c.send(3)`. The point is that the code should set `n` to 3, and then on the next loop, yield 3. But it does not get printed. Why?

Comment: it becomes clearer if you add a `print('newv: {}'.format(newv)` in the `if newv is not None:` block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never checked the return value of your `c.send(3)` call.
In fact, it appears that the `send` method itself advances the generator, 
so your missing `3` was `yield`ed in that `c.send(3)` call.

```
def countdown(n):
    while n >= 0:
        newv = yield n
        if newv is not None:
            n = newv
        else:
            n -= 1

c = countdown(5)
print(next(c))  
print(c.send(3))
print(next(c))
```

The output would be:

```
5
3
2
```

It is actually [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

> generator.send(value)
>
> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function.
>   The value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression.
>   The send() method ***returns*** the next value yielded by the generator, or
>   raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another
>   value.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing in `c.send()`. You are comparing when n==5, but you are not sending 5 (in your function is n-1), you are sending 3. For instance, it not prints 4.

Try the same code but with `c.send(5)`, it will print from 5 to 0.

```
c = countdown(5)
for n in c:
    print(n)
    if n == 5: c.send(5)
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't print from 5 to 0. It prints `5`, `3`, `2`, `1`, `0`, missing the `4`. Same problem.